# How can I create my own custom marker on google map like google map's default marker

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers

I am adding 2 custom markers on the map and finding the route between them. I am getting route from destination API and it works fine. But the problem is when this route is drawn on the map my custom markers position and drawn polyline is not 100% correct.

I am adding custom marker using this code:

`MarkerOptions().position(startPos).title("Start Point")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin_start)))`

and

`MarkerOptions().position(endPos).title("End Point")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin_end))`

But when I am using default markers everything works fine as I want.

`MarkerOptions().position(endPos).title("End Point")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker())`

[When I am adding my custom markers They are shown on the map like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbVXg.jpg)
As you can see from this image my circular marker is not pinned to the correct position

[But actually I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KyIl.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you are actually passing the float values for latitude and longitude. Please pass in the double values

Comment: Check your drawables, ic_pin_start & ic_pin_end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think You need to add an anchor point to your marker using this [this method in MarkerOptions class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float))

**Definition of this method**

Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.

The anchor specifies the point in the icon image that is anchored to the marker's position on the Earth's surface.

**For example,** to set the anchor point on the center of the icon you need to do:

```
markerOptions.anchor(0.2f, 0.2f);
```

adjust this anchor point according to your need and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, somehow it helped me. But still, when I zoom out the map, marker position is getting a little wrong. Anyway thank you

Comment: I am glad it helped.